# json given in django view. send to js of template as json

Tags: javascript, json, django

In the view, I have dictionary I once got from a json file, but it is manipulated. (I don't know whether this origin information is important.) So I can't just send the json files content. Please note: the json is in the format of `myjson = json.load(jsonstring)`.

I put that json to the context:

```
context = { 'testjson' : myjson }
```

In the templates body, I access that context variable:

```
<script>
  run("{{ testjson }}");
</script>
```

How has this run-function to deal to the arriving string? Please note: any special characters are html-escaped by django…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put quotes around your json string since you intend to use the json string as an object. Simply write `run({{ testjson }});` instead so that your function `run` can access the object as a hash directly.

Comment: this is right. but to be sure anything is loaded corectly, it's preferred to put `json.dumps(myjson)` to the dictionary, so the raw json string is going to be parsed. But since I didn't ask about converting to string…